# Query String parameter - Multi FilterMultiValue on different columns

Tags: url, query, query-string

Is there a way to combine FilterMultiValue on different columns?

ex
?FilterName=HomeCountry&FilterMultiValue=Norway;Global&FilterName=HostCountry&FilterMultiValue=US;Global

I want to filter on :

(First column I want to find all that have "norway" and "global")
and
(Second column I want to find all with "US" and "global")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in this [technet article](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/7b9759fb-863f-450d-8403-824eac371991/filter-lists-filtermultivalue-for-multiple-columns), a technet community support member answerd:

> We are unable to use FilterMultiValue work with multiple filters in this way and you may need programmatically effect

He also posted a [link to a blog](http://jasear.wordpress.com/2012/04/19/sharepoint-2010-basic-list-search-filter-webpart/), which shows how it can be done

I hope this will help you

Regards, Retech

Answer (score 0):

Enable the managed metadata navigation of the list. Try the url parameters below.

For metadata column:

```
?FilterField1=MyField1&FilterValue1=16,26&FilterField2=MyField2&FilterValue2=15,25&FilterLookupId1=1&FilterOp1=In&FilterLookupId2=1&FilterOp2=In
```

The integer is the id of the term in the `/Lists/TaxonomyHiddenList/AllItems.aspx`
Refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9883064/url-for-key-filter-on-document-list-view-in-sharepoint-2010)